# Pass variable in react

Tags: reactjs, state

I have his code where i try to pass a variable to the handleclick fcn and set state to that variable:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Initial State'
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(temp) {
    this.setState({
      name:temp
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick('name')}>Click Me</button>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

It doesn't work, can someone explain how to pass a variable and set state to it, if it's possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing `this.handleClick('name')` you are invoking the `handleClick` function directly on render. You want to give a function to the `onClick` prop that will be invoked on click.

**Example**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Initial State"
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(temp) {
    this.setState({
      name: temp
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick("name")}>Click Me</button>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!i tried marking this as the answer but i have to wait 10 mins

Comment: This will result in creating an arrow on each render which is undesirable if it's possible to avoid this.

Comment: So what would be a better solution?

Comment: @Jrobm2k9 [Don't worry about it](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578). If your use case absolutely demands that you prematurely optimize it, [you can use a data attribute](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7p1lm830p).